# IE7 and IE8, freezing on certain pages

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm working on a problem with a friend of mine, and am not having any luck.

He has a Drupal based website (http://www.njsmokes.com), which is working perfectly in Firefox & Chrome.  When using IE 7 or IE 8, after visiting certain pages - including the home page - the browser starts acting oddly.  You can click on links within the site, and it will load the new page, but the URL in the address bar doesn't change.  Once that happens, any time you type in a URL, the browser freezes and won't change pages.

There are some javascript errors on the homepage, but when he removes those elements (which he doesn't want to do for an extended time, this is an active business) the problems still occur.

He says Drupal & modules are up to date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Work on it offline or on a separate installation - then you don't have to worry about it being an active business.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same scenerio..
the culprit turned out to be a function that was trying to refer to a global variable (window.foo) that was undefined. In my case, the unknown variable was being passed as a parameter to another function.. though that shouldn't matter.

By declaring the variable in a global scope (ie: window.foo='';).. things fell into place.

Not sure which I love more.. legacy code.. or legacy browsers :)